# Change timezone of browser

Tags: timezone, browser

I need to run browser with a timezone other than operating system's time zone. Is there any way to customize time zone in any browser or is there any plugin available that provides such functionality?

Comment: What Operating System are you on?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I don't want to change system's time zone.

Comment: In this Regard, I've used this script on OXS: https://gist.github.com/prasadsilva/225fd0394a51e52bf62f Works like a charm!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are on Linux, you can launch a process while setting an environment variable for the lifetime of the process. Linux uses the environment variable `TZ` for time zone configuration. For example, the following command will run firefox using UTC timezone.

```
TZ=UTC firefox
```

Comment: May I add, if you are coding a web app and the purpose of this is to show different data to different users based on their timezone, I highly suggest to do this from a server-side perspective: you can still guess timezone from client browser, but move timezone configuration to the server side and possibly let users change their timezones from your webapp. If you still need to do certain date-related calculations on the client side, send the timezone configuration from the server.

Comment: Thank you for answer and the advice. I will keep that in mind while developing a web app.

Comment: Just to drop a note here for Windows users: This technique is only reliable on Linux and OSX.  Don't use on Windows.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285315/634824).  Thanks.

Comment: what about chrome?